# asp.net custom server control design time support

Tags: asp.net, custom-server-controls

I'm having issues with a custom panel control in design view.  Overriding the render method has no affect at design-time.

If I extend a textbox as follows the design time showed the div tag and then the textbox control. Tried the same with the panel control and it did not show the div with the here text in it. Seems since panel is a container control it works differently in design view. Really frustrating.  Any ideas on how to get my design-time to render the way I want it to?

```
Public Class textboxextend
  Inherits TextBox

  Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    writer.RenderBeginTag("div")
    writer.Write("here")
    writer.RenderEndTag()
    MyBase.Render(writer)
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class panelextend
  Inherits Panel

  Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)

    writer.RenderBeginTag("div")
    writer.Write("here")
    writer.RenderEndTag()
    MyBase.Render(writer)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: FYI tried debugging the extended Panel class, and when the component is added at design time, it doesnt fire any of the usual events (RenderControl, Render, RenderChildren, RenderContents, CreateChildControls, OnLoad or OnPreRender)... it does however call OnInit, which doesn't help since all the controls have been created and added to the Panel's Controls collection at New()..

This appears to only affect extending the Panel class, works fine when extending TextBox or TreeView class etc...

In other words, I'm looking for an answer too :(

Answer (score 0):

Panel doesn't work the same way as TextBox (and most controls). There is no Render method, so the override is never called. Panel uses RenderBeginTag and RenderEndTag.
You may want to use the AddAttributesToRender method too.